# android.support.v7 with `ActionBarActivity` no menu shows

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-support-library

In the new update Google has released a new API support library, that supports the ActionBar in API level 7+.

I used ActionBarSherlock until this update and I wrote the code to load the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and the menu file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item_menu_ok" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_ok"
        android:title="@string/ok" android:showAsAction="always"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/item_menu_cancel" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        android:title="@string/cancel" android:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

To set up the menu buttons on the action bar. This code worked perfectly with ActionBarSherlock. But when I changed the action bar to the new support library, the buttons are not shown in the action bar. Even if they are set as `android:showAsAction="always"`. And when I debug the code, the function `menu.getSize()` return 2, and that is correct, but no buttons are shown..

Why are the buttons not shown in the new support library?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try pressing the MENU button on your device or emulator, and see if they appear in the overflow.

If they do, then the problem is that your `<menu>` XML needs to change. Menu XML that works with ActionBarSherlock and the native API Level 11+ action bar will not work with the AppCompat action bar backport.

Your menu XML would need to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
    <item android:id="@+id/item_menu_ok" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_ok"
        android:title="@string/ok" yourapp:showAsAction="always"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/item_menu_cancel" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        android:title="@string/cancel" yourapp:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

And you would need to use the same `yourapp` prefix for anything else related to the action bar (e.g., `yourapp:actionLayout`).

You can see this covered in [the action bar documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems).

Comment: Yea, the problem was the `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. This is change for the Support v7? Cause in `ActionBarSherlock` my old code worked perfectly

Comment: @nrofis: I have no idea why AppCompat cannot use `android:showAsAction` the way ActionBarSherlock can.

Comment: Thanks this is a tiny and weird change that i managed to overlook!

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was looking for this as well. To clarify, does "yourapp" include the "com.xxx.package" or just "package"?

Comment: No replacement its literally "yourapp"

Comment: @Wenger: The `yourapp` on the attributes needs to match the `yourapp` namespace declaration in the root element. AFAIK, so long as those names are the same (and are valid for XML), they can be whatever string you want.

Comment: Note if you are using Android Studio: Make sure to `Build > Rebuild Project`. I couldn't figure out why mine wouldn't work, but it was simply because it needed a rebuild.

Comment: For some reason, it still doesn't appear on the top right corner of my app but it shows at the bottom middle of the string. @CommonsWare Any Idea why?

I have done everything you have mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a little to [the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17881737/1065835)

If you want to see *both text and an icon*, please use `withText` in `showAsAction`
I've just tested it; when I used `always` or `ifRoom` without `withText`, I only saw an icon.