# Android AppCompat display overflow button on ActionBar - API level 8

Tags: android

I'm trying to display overflow button on ActionBar on devices using API level 8. I was trying do it according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881547/android-support-v7-with-actionbaractivity-no-menu-shows) post but I can't see overflow button on ActionBar. Can someone give me an advice? Thank you for response.

Comment: Post the XML your having trouble with.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?