# Why Activity doesn't show button on actionbar?

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar-compat

I'm starting an activity from a webView, using a JavascriptInterface. This is the code:
I add Interface to the webview:

```
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyInterface (this), "MyInterface ");
```

This is MyInterface:

```
public class MyInterface {

MyActivity fatherActivity;

public MyInterface (){}


public MyInterface (MainActivity fatherActivity){
    this.fatherActivity=fatherActivity;
}

    @JavascriptInterface
public void open(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(fatherActivity, NewActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Context ctx = fatherActivity.getApplicationContext();
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

this is the res/menu/refMenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuRefresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>
```

In NewActivity I put

```
   public class NewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.refMenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
 }
```

And of course I used supported theme in AndroidManifest:

```
        <activity
        android:name="my.package.NewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    </activity>
```

If I put the menu in my first Activity it goes well...but in NewActivity it's not showing.

What do you think is wrong?

**UPDATE:** It seems that extending ActionBarActivity can be a problem because if I make the first activity as subclass of ActionBarActivity neither it shows the item on the action bar. But I would kepp my app compatible with Gingerbread so I must use ActionBarActivity. Any solution?

**SOLVED:** [android.support.v7 with `ActionBarActivity` no menu shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881547/android-support-v7-with-actionbaractivity-no-menu-shows)