# Android menu item showAsAction="always" doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, menu

I have tried setting the:

```
android:showAsAction=".."
```

to every one of these:

```
ifRoom, never, withText, always, collapseActionView
```

but I always got the same result, which is not having any buttons on the action bar, so I have to press the 'menu' button.

Here is a picture of the menu now :

[image: current menu]

```
<item android:id="@+id/smth1"
    android:title="@string/smth1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1" />
```

I have even tried adding this:

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

into application manifest file, but with no positive result (nothing changed).

I have tried running it on various kind of APIs (14, 16, 17, 19), but with the same result.

If my question seems to be unclear, here is a picture of a menu, which I would like to have:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you use the v7 support library because there is many problems due to this library ? ...

Comment: Yes, I use appcompat_v7 as a support library.

Comment: Then search a bit in this way because there is a lot of "problems" with this library, here are a link which can be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17881737/2545832 (I think it'll solve your problem)

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.support.v7 with \`ActionBarActivity\` no menu shows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881547/android-support-v7-with-actionbaractivity-no-menu-shows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe just don't have enough space, you should first remove the title from your `Activity` by adding this to your `onCreate` method:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Then you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) that the maximum number of icons you can display is directly linked to the width of your screen, on small phones you will only be able to see 2 icons in the `ActionBar`.

Comment: I have enough, I have tried it with many different resolutions. But thanks for a reply.

Comment: How do you inflate the menu in the code? XML only is not enough.

Comment: `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 return true;
}`

Comment: Are you still using `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`? Because this will remove the buttons from the top.

Comment: And puts them at the bottom. But hey, it works now thanks to previous replies. Thx to everyone.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the compatibility namespace ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored))

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_add_size"
    android:title="@string/menu_add_item"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" 
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Once you're using that you can use as many menu buttons as will fit. You're no longer limited to just two buttons + overflow showing.